# What class gives access to what is called Properties in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-package

I'm working on an extension that targets C++ projects. It needs to retrieve a list of IncludePaths for a project. In VS IDE, it's menu -> Project -> Properties -> Configuration properties -> C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. That's what I need to get programmatically in my extension.

I have a corresponding VCProject instance, I also have a VCConfiguration instance. Judging from the [Automation Model Overview chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb164692.aspx), the project and configuration both have a collection of properties. However, they don't seem to available. Neither VCConfiguration nor VCProject classes have any property collection, not even when I inspect the contents of VCConfiguration and VCProject objects at runtime.

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration.aspx) also don't provide any insights. VCConfiguration interface has a property PropertySheets, but after examining it at runtime with the help of debugger I have determined it's not what I need.

P. S. If I could just get the value of Command Line property (Project -> Properties -> Configuration properties -> C++ -> Command Line), the list of arguments compiler will be called with for a given project - that's also fine by me, one can parse that string to get all include paths.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to remove some of my extra crap... but this should do the trick:

```
  public string GetCommandLineArguments( Project p )
  {
     string returnValue = null;

     try
     {
        if ( ( Instance != null ) )
        {
           Properties props = p.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties;
           try
           {
              returnValue = props.Item( "StartArguments" ).Value.ToString();
           }
           catch
           {
              returnValue = props.Item( "CommandArguments" ).Value.ToString();
              // for c++
           }
        }
     }
     catch ( Exception ex )
     {
        Logger.Info( ex.ToString() );
     }

     return returnValue;
  }
```

These will probably help, too: (so you can see what properties a project has and their values)

```
public void ShowProjectProperties( Project p )
      {
         try
         {
            if ( ( Instance != null ) )
            {
               string msg = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( p.FullName ) + " has the following properties:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

               Properties props = p.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties;
               List< string > values = props.Cast< Property >().Select( prop => SafeGetPropertyValue( prop) ).ToList();
               msg += string.Join( Environment.NewLine, values );
               MessageDialog.ShowMessage( msg );
            }
         }
         catch ( Exception ex )
         {
            Logger.Info( ex.ToString() );
         }
      }

      public string SafeGetPropertyValue( Property prop )
      {
         try
         {
            return string.Format( "{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value );
         }
         catch ( Exception ex )
         {
            return string.Format( "{0} = {1}", prop.Name, ex.GetType() );
         }
      }
```

Comment: did this help with your problem?